# Array Bash printing elements in a loop of multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, printing

I have multiple arrays ( I limit it to 3 ) & first time using arrays
The length of the arrays are the same. They correspond to the same records
So array a, b and c values are listed below:

```
array a   = 1 2 3 4 5 
array b   = a b c d e 
array c   = v w x y z
```

I need to print then content so the output is like this on each line

```
1 a v
2 b w
3 c x
4 d y
5 e z
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty straight forward using any BASH array tutorial. Have you tried it?

Comment: As of now, you don't have arrays.  You don't even have _strings_.  You have _syntax error_.

Comment: Do you know Bash? There's nothing too difficult in setting up an array in Bash. Do you have any code you've tried?

Comment: yes see the code below David. It works. IS there an easier way to do this that you recommend

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more bash-ful version (if you will):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# initialize arrays
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
b=(a b c d e)
c=(v w x y z)

# count elements (assuming all arrays are the same size)
numElems=${#a[@]}

# loop over all elements
for (( i = 0; i < numElems; i++ )); do
  # -e ensures that escape sequences such as \t are recognized
  echo -e "${a[i]}\t${b[i]}\t${c[i]}"
done
```

Comment: this is not working properly. There are two sets of out put and it's just not working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'two sets of output'? What, specifically, is not working? You should make sure that it is `bash` (and not `sh`, for instance) that is processing your script - I've added a shebang line to my answer. What platform and bash version are you on?

Comment: @mklement0 Just a small error : you should use `"${a[$i]}\t${b[$i]}\t${c[$i]}"` instead of `"${a[i]}\t${b[i]}\t${c[i]}"` ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann Thanks, but it should work _either_ way: array subscripts (as of at least bash 3.2.51, but probably since much earlier) are evaluated in an _arithmetic_ context (like `$(( ... ))`), so the `$` prefix when referencing variables is _optional_.

Comment: @mklement0 Indeed, I knew it inside double parentheses but I didn't know for `${a[i]}`. It would have been better if I test :) . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked it out, hopefully there is a better way.  There are 3 arrays sample listed above, Each array has a list of values in it. Since they are of equal length. This is what can be done . The $'\t'  puts a tab in between.

```
s=${#a[@]}
counter=0
echo $counter
while [[ $counter -lt $s ]];
do
echo ${a[$counter]}  $'\t'  ${b[$counter]}  $'\t'  ${c[$counter]}
counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done
```